# How to make user account always use default configuration

Tags: users

I need to set up a student account on school computers so that it always uses default configuration - windows sizes, apps layout etc. and also always deletes files after reboot or log out.

It's basically what a guest account is but there are some limitations in it, like I cannot launch wine apps and use samba for local network.

By default configuration I mean not Ubuntu default conf-n, but all changes I do - wallpaper, apps layout etc.

Is there a way to achieve this on Ubuntu 15.10?
Help's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into Terminalservers, since they seem perfectly suited for your needs. Look for LTSP (Linux Terminal Server Project).

A Terminalserver setup means that there is only a very basic system installed on your (thin-)clients, and everything that is done actually happens on the server. This way, you can also save a lot of cash on the actual pcs that your students are supposed to use.

A whole bunch of schools in Greece use LTSP, as is described here: [Link](http://www.ltsp.org/stories/viewstory/?story_id=8&secret=ed1d48)
Maybe you can even get in touch with one of their admins to ask them about the setup!

Comment: Sounds interesting, but we don't have a server in our possesion or means to buy it. There are 12 standard computers in a classroom.

Comment: In that case, try the following: Create a copy of every users home directory after the initial setup, and then run a script at boot (or maybe better shutdown since it might take a minute or 2 to run) that copies the "default" homedirectories to /home and deletes the others. Because non-root users can only write to their home, that should solve it. Remember that if you want to change something in the homedirectories permanently, you need to manually copy them to the source directory for the bootscript again!

Comment: Sounds complicated) I definitely don't know how to do this on my own. What script and how should I use it?